# Cross section of actin network in neurites

Tags: molecular-biology, neuroscience

for a simulation I am developing I would like to know how the actin network in neurites is distributed.

Is actin confined to the periphery or is the whole neurite shaft containing actin with a rather constant density?

If you have any papers backing up the one or the other view don't hesitate to pass the link.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: does this help? (http://www.neuraldevelopment.com/content/pdf/1749-8104-6-27.pdf)

Comment: on first sight this paper only gives a 2D distribution of actin over the whole neuron or? I would like to know what you would see if you cut a neurite and subsequently look "into" the cross section. Is the actin only found on the outer part of the cross section or evenly distributed across the circle?

Comment: Just look at papers doing confocal microscopy/imaging of actin with z-stacking (z refers to the axis) since thats the main approach people use for 3D imaging and people also use delta vision microscope with z-stacking and deconvolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actin is required for the neurite architecture and is present throughout the shaft (along the direction of the neurite process)

See these images.

---

[image]

[**[Source]**](http://cornellcelldevbiology.org/sung/researchunconventional.html)

---

[image]

[**[Source]**](http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~pwm/web/?section=introduction&page=neurons)

These are not from research papers but the sources are trustworthy.

Comment: From those images I would not deduce that the neurite shaft has a substantial actin skeleton but rather a small amount of "misguided" filaments. Is that right?

Comment: Why would you assume some misguided filaments? The region indicated as meshwork is essential for the structure.

Comment: In the second picture actin and tubulin are labeled. I cannot see any actin along the shaft except of growth cone areas. So there is no substantial amount of actin concentrated along the shaft. Or?

Comment: OK I didnt understand what you meant by shaft. I thought you were referring to the filopodial region. Yes actin is not abundant in the axonal regions